# How to deploy Meteor Application on cPanel shared hosting

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy a meteor.js application on cPanel shared hosting. I don't have access to their cli.
I have followed this tutorial [Host your Node.js app on Shared hosting. Go beyond localhost.](https://medium.com/@pampas93/host-your-node-js-app-on-shared-hosting-go-beyond-localhost-73ab923e6691)

Now I am having hard time with a couple of things. I can't find any tutorial specific for meteor.js which is why I am facing some issues. Which are as follows

**1.** **Without meteor Build**

I uploaded the development version of my code. i.e the one with client,server,lib folders(without meteor build). The problem is that I am not sure about the "Application startup file".

I tried with "./client/main.js" and "./server/main.js" seperately but the site then returns 503.

**2.** **With meteor Build**

I then built my application and the build was generated with some errors. I then uploaded the tar.gz file and went with the main.js as Application Startup file. But now the cPanel is unable to detect package.json

Can someone please refer to a full guide of how to deploy a meteor app with cPanel.

Comment: In case of 1. you need to run `meteor`, i.e., you'll need to first install meteor on the shared instance. In case 2.: what were the errors? Also, once deployed, you need to follow the steps in the included README file to start the deployed app.

Comment: About the errors during build `meteor build --directory "C:\Users\alam computer\OneDrive\Desktop\node.js\Build" --server http://localhost:3000/` this is the command I used. I tried without ip but it says to specify a server. the error which appears is `Error: Command failed: C:\Users\alam computer\OneDrive\Desktop\node.js\simple_ToDo\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\version
'C:\Users\alam' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Also i am using windows and not ubuntu so export commands don't work. do you know an alternate

Comment: Would you consider `mup` (meteor-up) for deployment? It automates mostly all steps involved.

Comment: Try to build to a folder that doesn't have a space in the path.